# how to solve problem ord utf_8 in simple pythhon 3.8 programm?

Tags: python, utf-8, ord

I run the program b.py how can I make the third line of the output look the same as the first
b.py:

```
S='----Ăł---'

def x(S):
  print(f'{S=}')
  RES=[]
  for s in S:
    RES+=[ord(s)]
  return RES

print(x(S))                           # first line result
with open('b.py') as F:
  print(x(F.readlines()[0]))          # thrid line result
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
open the file with encofding = 'utf_8':

```
     `with open ('b.py, encoding =' utf_8 ') as F:
        ....
     '
```